# Call a function from a separate class not working

Tags: swift, lottie

I am calling a function in a different class that simply removes a lottie animation. I do this by calling...

```
RedeemController().removeAnimationFromSuperview()
```

Which enters the function (as proven by a print statement). However the animation does not disappear from the view.

When I call the same function from within the class that the animation is defined, the animation is removed from the view as expected. Here is the function. Very simple.

```
    fileprivate func removeAnimationFromSuperview(){
        animationViewDraw.removeFromSuperview()
        print("Entered")

    }
```

I would expect this animation to disappear. Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new instance of `RedeemController` that has it's own properties, instead you have to use the instance that you currently have 
`myControllerInstance.removeAnimationFromSuperview()`